# Вывод массива в одном цикле, но в разных шаблонах

Tags: php, foreach

Нужно вывести массив циклом `foreach`, но так, чтобы первый элемент массива выводился, например, в блоке `<div class='name_1'>`, а второй и последующие в блоке `<div class='name_2'>`. Суть в том, что первый нужно вывести в блоке большего размера, чем последующие. Как-то это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Вариантов куча. Можно, например, извлечь первый элемент через [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php), а дальше уже простым `foreach`, либо получить первый элемент через [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.reset.php), а затем делаем срез массива через [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php) и пробегаемся циклом

Comment: ВОРОН, я так понимаю, что, если извлечь первый элемент массива, то придётся проходится отдельным циклом по нему, а потом отдельным циклом последующие элементы выводить. А я хотел за один цикл, то есть foreach($Array AS $Key){ А тут уже вывод}

Comment: зачем отдельный цикл на первый элемент? Он уже выбран - никакой цикл ему не нужен

Comment: Не совсем понял. Можете на примере показать?

Comment: пример: `$arr = [1,2,3]; $first = array_shift($arr); echo "$first\n"; foreach ($arr as $value) { echo $value; }`

Comment: ВОРОН, ваш вариант понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поискал у Яндекса, самый первый сайт в поиске, это ответ на ваш вопрос - [читать](http://www.webdev.ru/articles/foreach-obrabotka-pervogo-i-poslednego-elementa.html)

А [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop) на Stackoverflow обсуждение. Думаю, вам стоит обратить внимание на:

```
foreach($array as $element) {
    if ($element === reset($array))
        echo 'FIRST ELEMENT!';

    if ($element === end($array))
        echo 'LAST ELEMENT!';
}
```

Как уже в комментариях выше написал @ВОРОН

Answer (score 0):

Заведите счетчик. Если итерация первая, то увеличиваете его. Чтоб не городить код можно сам счетчик в класс записывать.

```
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $item)
{
    echo '<div class="item_'.$i.'"></div>';

    if($i < 2)
    {
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Счётчик в класс не получится, класс я для примера указал, шаблоны вывода отличаются не одним классом + там ещё отдельные атрибуты style=''' разные прописаны